# Design without having multiple definitions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, winapi, compact-framework

I have a sample application and user control which uses separate copy of structure and enum.
I want to know how to define this enum and structure, in order to use in my sample application as well as in my user control without having multiple definitions . i.e. only one copy of enum and structure should be present.
If I do this code duplication can be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Define the types you want to use in more than one place in a DLL. Just add a new project of type "Class Library" to your soultion, put your code in it and add references to this project in all the other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

if i have 10 different enums then i need to make 10 different DLL's.
its increases the complexity i.e count of DLL are more.
But in c/c++ only one ".h" is enough to access across the project. 
so how to achieve this in c#.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need 10 different DLLs? You are creating a shared class library. You would just define all your enums in the library and reference the library in all your projects that use them.

Comment: yeah,, i do create as u told.. but the problem is code separation will not be there i mean if i give that .dll to some body they will be having access to all the unused enums. but in c++ number of .h increases here number of .dll increases

Comment: I still can't see where the multiple dlls are going to come about. If you have 10 enums that need to be used across multiple projects. If you put them into a separate library project, then reference that library project in the projects that require them, then I can't see the need for defining multiple dlls?

Comment: And what is the problem with somebody having access to "unused" enums?

Comment: @James: yes i do create a DLL, which has 10 enums.then i will reference them into multiple project i agree with this solution. But all projects which refer a DLL may not require all enum's, in this case your solution comes i.e creating multiple DLL and distribute which ever necessary to project. Is any other way to achieve this? i mean with out making DLL,like making .h file in C/C++ using it,is there any way similar to C/C++ in C#.

Comment: No, there is no other way. Just put ALL your enums in ONE DLL and add this to the project. Unused enums will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate library project for this. Place all your common code into that and reference it in both your application/user control projects. Alternatively, create your UserControl under the same project as your application.